# Specific Data Validation for Excel

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I would like assistance on an Excel validation formula for the following 2 situations, with the following 2 conditions, the first letter of the first 2 words are uppercase, while the rest are in lowercase:

[5 letters].[4 letters].[3 numbers]_[2 letters]
example of valid data: Happy.Lane.523_ty

[5 letters].[4 letters][3 numbers]!_[2 letters]
example of valid data: Happy.Lane487!_tr

Comment: what have your tried so far?

Comment: Formula 1: =AND(UPPER(LEFT(A1,1)&MID(A1,7,1)),LOWER(MID(A1,2,4)&MID(A1,8,3)&RIGHT(A1,2)),VALUE(MID(A1,11,3))<1000,EXACT(MID(A1,6,1),”.”),EXACT(MID(A1,14,2),”!_”))

Formula 2: =AND(UPPER(LEFT(A1,1)&MID(A1,7,1)),LOWER(MID(A1,2,4)&MID(A1,8,3)&RIGHT(A1,2)),VALUE(MID(A1,12,3))<1000,EXACT(MID(A1,6,1),”.”),EXACT(MID(A1,11,1),”.”,EXACT(MID(A1,15,1),”_”))

Comment: Koh Chin Aun  Edit your question and add the formula(s) you have tried there.

Answer (score 0):

Probably doable through a formula but first thing that came to mind validating a pattern was regular expressions. Here is a pattern you could try:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]{4}\.[A-Z][a-z]{3}(?:\.\d{3}|\d{3}!)_[a-z]{2}$
```

You can check the pattern online [here](https://regex101.com/r/Qrcr5U/1).

---

To implement this you could use an UDF, for example:

```
Function RegexMatch(str As String, pat As String) As Boolean
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = pat
        RegexMatch = .Test(str)
    End With
End Function
```

Call in a cell through: `=RegexMatch(A1,"^[A-Z][a-z]{4}\.[A-Z][a-z]{3}(?:\.\d{3}|\d{3}!)_[a-z]{2}$")`

---

With a single Excel formula you could also use:

```
=AND(EXACT(LEFT(A1,10),PROPER(LEFT(A1,10))),(MID(A1,6,1)="."),(OR(AND(MID(A1,11,1)=".",ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,12,3))),AND(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,11,3)),MID(A1,14,1)="!"))),(MID(A1,15,1)="_"),(EXACT(RIGHT(A1,2),LOWER(RIGHT(A1,2)))),(LEN(A1)=17))
```

Which also will result in either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks! It works for the first case. Possible to also help me for the second case too?

Comment: It validates both cases on my end. Btw, please consider to also revisit you older question and reply and possibly accept an answer given

Comment: Noted and thank you for the assistance! The formula provided works for both cases.

Comment: @KohChinAun, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you are not familiar with what I meant.